# Using GitHub Source Code to modify existing Rally apps

Tags: rally

I'm fairly new to the Rally development scene, but I've been tasked with making a few custom apps for my workplace this summer.

I've been trying to use the GitHub source code on pre-existing applications and extend them to create these apps, but I keep running into errors with trying to modify them.

My question is this- is the code provided already supposed to be working, or should it just be used as a starting point?

The reason I ask is because I did no modifications to the source code retrieved from GitHub, but when I tried to execute the code, it didn't work. Specifically, I was working with the Release Burndown code (provided here: https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/tree/master/src/apps/charts/burndown), and each time I build it with the rally-app-builder, the HTML that gets spit out into the deploy folder is not even functional. The error my console receives is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined". This error makes absolutely no sense to me. Could someone elaborate on what's going on?

I've already watched the video series by David Thomas on getting started with Rally, but if anyone has any other great resources that can help me get up to speed, I would greatly appreciate it.

Any and all help is welcomed.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

The vast majority of the apps in the catalog should work externally/in standalone dev mode.  There is a known issue with Rally App Builder with some of the apps that share code outside of its home directory which is probably what you're running into.  (You can see in that app's [config.json](https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/blob/master/src/apps/charts/burndown/config.json) that it is referencing shared files a directory or two above its own directory).

The workaround is that you can always build the app and then in your browser you can browse to deploy/App-external.html to test it.  You should be able to set up rally-app-builder watch in another console to automatically rebuild it as you make changes as well.

Welcome to the Rally developer community!

After spending a bit more time on this I've come to the conclusion that this is not a particularly well written app for standalone use.  But you should be able to get by your issue by changing this code in BurndownApp.js:

```
config: {
    defaultSettings: {
        chartTimebox: 'release' //used to be undefined
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the issue here is that I can't get passed the Uncaught TypeError... How am I supposed to modify the code to work if it doesn't even work in the first place immediately after pasting the source code in?

Comment: I just tried your app, and you're right- this is actually a problem with this app specifically.  I loaded http://localhost:1337/deploy/App-external.html and got the error you mentioned.

Comment: thanks so much!! It's working perfectly now. I was wondering if you would have any advice / suggestions for how to modify this code the way that I want it to behave. I'm trying to have a metric line that will show how many points have been completed, but I'm not quite sure how points are calculated as "completed" in Rally. My metric line right now is displaying what the "accepted" stories line would show, and I'm not exactly sure if they're synonymous or not. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: All that metric code is in the BurnDownCalculator.js file.  I am by no means a chart expert, but it seems like it is aggregating accepted as one bucket and everything else as the other